# Message : Error issuing app only token; ServiceName *_sharepoint_com_sites_ipmcomdocs;

Tags: sharepoint, k2

I am getting this Error as regards to Processes on K2 which uses the sharepoint, online sharepoint library, does this have to do with the online sharepoint or is something missing Kindly advice.

Kind of very new to sharepoint Errors.